# Sonarqube client fails to parse pytest coverage results

Tags: python, sonarqube, pytest, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to set up a gitlab ci pipeline for a python project and I'm having some issues with sonarqube client which is not able to pars the coverage.xml file

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
INFO: Python test coverage
INFO: Parsing report '/builds/core-tech/tools/nlu/mix-nlu-middleware/server/tests/cov.xml'
WARN: Invalid directory path in 'source' element: /bolt-webserver/bolt
WARN: Invalid directory path in 'source' element: /bolt-webserver/tests
ERROR: Cannot resolve the file path 'base.py' of the coverage report, the file does not exist in all <source>.
ERROR: Cannot resolve 404 file paths, ignoring coverage measures for those files
INFO: Sensor Cobertura Sensor for Python coverage [python] (done) | time=74ms
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor [python]
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor [python] (done) | time=20ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
```

The coverage file (cov.xml) starts with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<coverage branch-rate="0" branches-covered="0" branches-valid="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.3476" lines-covered="10369" lines-valid="29833" timestamp="1564079534753" version="4.4.2">
    <!-- Generated by coverage.py: https://coverage.readthedocs.io -->
    <!-- Based on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cobertura/web/master/htdocs/xml/coverage-04.dtd -->
    <sources>
        <source>/bolt-webserver/bolt</source>
        <source>/bolt-webserver/tests</source>
    </sources>
    <packages>
        <package branch-rate="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.55" name=".">
            <classes>
                <class branch-rate="0" complexity="0" filename="base.py" line-rate="0.5955" name="base.py">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines>
                        <line hits="1" number="1"/>
                        <line hits="1" number="2"/>
                        <line hits="1" number="3"/>
                        <line hits="1" number="4"/>
                        <line hits="1" number="5"/>
                        <line hits="1" number="7"/>
                        <line hits="1" number="9"/>
                        <line hits="1" number="10"/>
  .......................
```

Sonar is called like this:

```
- sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=mix-nlu-middleware -Dsonar.sources=./server -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_SERVER_HOST -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN -Dsonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=server/tests/cov.xml -Dsonar.junit.reportPaths=server/tests/junit-report.xml
```

The project tree looks like this:

```
.
+-- CONTRIBUTING.md
+-- gen_version.sh
+-- package-lock.json
+-- README.md
+-- scripts
│   +-- .....
+-- server
│   +-- alembic.ini
│   +-- bolt
│   │   +-- .....
│   +-- Bolt.egg-info
│   │   +-- .....
│   +-- conf
│   │   +-- .....
│   +-- dev-requirements.txt
│   +-- Dockerfile
│   +-- Dockerfile-dev
│   +-- http.log
│   +-- MANIFEST.in
│   +-- pytest.ini
│   +-- requirements.txt
│   +-- scripts
│   │   +-- .....
│   +-- sdks
│   │   +-- ....
│   +-- server.log
│   +-- setup.py
│   +-- templates
│   │   +-- .....
│   +-- tests
│   │   +-- .....
│   \-- version.properties
\-- test.txt
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

I've also tried to create the path /bolt-webserver/bolt in the root folder of the project and file system but still no luck.

The 'base.py' file and the others mentioned in the conv.xml are located under '/builds/core-tech/tools/nlu/mix-nlu-middleware/server/tests'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test/Test Coverage with Python in Sonar not showing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844451/test-test-coverage-with-python-in-sonar-not-showing-up)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue with GitHub Actions, was able to resolve by specifying `relative_files = True` in `.coveragerc`.

```
[coverage:run]
relative_files = True
source = my_project/
branch = True
```

This is also documented on SonarCloud's [docs](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/enriching/test-coverage/python-test-coverage/)

> Note that we specify relative_files = True in the tox.ini file to ensure that GitHub Actions will correctly parse your coverage results.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also helped with `pytest-cov`. However, I added the following to `pyproject.toml`:
```
[tool.coverage.run]
source = ['my_project']
relative_files = true
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to assist sonarqube to found proper file, an easy way could be include the following step in your GH actions after running the tests and generate the report, and before calling souncarcloud scan

```
--> step that run tests

      - name: fix code coverage paths
        run: |
          sed -i 's/\/home\/runner\/work\/<your-repo>\/<your-repo>\//\/github\/workspace\//g' cover/coverage.xml

--> step that call sonar qube report
```

(I imagine your repo is `bolt-webserver`)

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem seem to have come from the cov.xml content. It seems sonarqube is not able to locate the test files based on their name only: filename="base.py"
In order to fix the problem I had to update the cov.xml so that the filename fields contained the full file path. filename="/base.py"

Comment: did you do this manually or were you able to do it in the pytest run?

Comment: I had to do it manually. Well i wrote a script to do it for me

Comment: Mind to share the script? ;)

Comment: Bump! How do you find the path of the file from just the filename? I would like to see that script as well.

Comment: ...and Bump again! @gheorghievgheniev we need to know :) having the same problem at the moment

Comment: did anyone find how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing as stated by Adrian at https://community.sonarsource.com/t/python-coverage-analysis-warning/62629/7

Seems like there is a problem with using `source`, works when using `include`
instead.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in python projects that use [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) with [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/) and have the integration with SonarQube being executed from both `GitLab CI` and `GitHub Actions`.

After spending hours trying each one of the previous answers shared here, the solution for my case was quite simple:

- set the working directory from where SonarQube scanner is executed to the subdirectory where the relative paths are calculated in the test coverage report.

#### Example:

In my case my repository layout is similar to:

```
a-file
another-file
project-1/
    app/
    tests/
some-other-dir/
some-other-file
...
```

Given that I want the scanner to collect test coverage results for the code in `project-1`, then `project-1` should be set as the working directory.

Sample solution, using GitHub actions + [sonarqube-scan-action](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-scan-action#usage) and setting `projectBaseDir`:

```yaml
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          # Disable shallow clones, as recommended by SonarQube for improved analysis and reports
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Run tests
        run: # command to run tests and generate coverage report

      - name: SonarQube Scan
        uses: sonarsource/sonarqube-scan-action@master
        with:
          # projectBaseDir: path/to/my/sub_dir/with/app_and_tests_folders
          projectBaseDir: project-1
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONARQUBE_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONARQUBE_URL }}
```

In GitLab CI I achieved the same using the Docker image [sonar-scanner-cli-docker](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli-docker/blob/af3f4b4b4e100164c1439cec77dd0e8ae5cb4045/5/Dockerfile#L54) and setting the image environment variable `SRC_PATH` with the path to my project subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74141082/2095866) by @zeshuaro,
I added the following to `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.coverage.run]
source = ['my_project']
relative_files = true
```

To make it work with `pytest-cov` and not create additional files.